# Error: selector does not match template labels

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

My task is to add a label named "app" to all `deployments`, `daemonsets`, and `cronjobs` so that it's easier to query our apps across the stack in our monitoring tools. This way, we can build dashboards that use a single selector, namely app.

To avoid downtime I've decided to resolve this issue in the following steps:

1. Add labels to dev, test & stage environments.
2. Add labels to prod env's.
3. Deploy (1)
4. Deploy (2)
5. Delete old labels & update the services of dev to use the new labels. Then test & deploy. (**currently on this step**)
6. Repeat (5) for stage.
7. Repeat (5) for prod.

When using `$ kubectl apply` to update the resources I've added the "app" label to/replaced "service" label with "app" labels to, I run into the following error:

> Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:
>   {*longAssPatchWhichIWon'tIncludeButYaGetThePoint*} to: &{0xc421b02f00
>   0xc420803650 default provisioning
>   manifests/prod/provisioning-deployment.yaml 0xc 42000c6f8 3942200
>   false} for: "manifests/prod/provisioning-deployment.yaml":
>   Deployment.apps "provisioning" is invalid: s
>   pec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value:
>   map[string]string{"app":"provisioning", "component" :"marketplace"}:
>   `selector` does not match template `labels`

I need some insights on why it's throwing this error.

Comment: Can you share yaml for the deployment? One quick reminder, your deployment's `spec.selector` has to match labels of `spec.template.metadata.labels`.

Comment: @EmruzHossain I understand but even after that update I still received the same error. I've included my .yaml file.

Comment: You should insert your code or manifests or something like to your problem description instead of inserting them by link

Comment: Correct your indentation in `spec.selector.matchLabels`, `spec.selector.matchLabels.app` and `spec.selector.matchLabels.component`. You have used 4 spaces instead of 2 spaces.

Answer (score 34):

It seems you are in trouble. Check this section: [Label selector updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates)

> Note: In API version `apps/v1`, a Deployment’s label selector is immutable after it gets created.

So, this line say you can not update `selector` once deployment is created. Selector can not be changed for any API version except `apps/v1beta1` and `extension/v1beta1`. Ref: [TestDeploymentSelectorImmutability](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/dad6741530b0c69587a71a6c08544b4c9412fa01/test/integration/deployment/deployment_test.go#L226).

One possible workaround might be to keep the old labels and adding new labels along with old ones. This way, you don't have to update `selector`. Deployment will select pods using old labels but your dashboard can select using new labels. This might not meet your requirement but I don't see any better way.

Comment: The API version I have for that file is extension/v1beta1. So I should be able to change/update the selector right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. I haven't tried. You have read  `Label selector updates` section I have linked in my answer, right? There are some problem in changing `selector`. Old ReplicaSet will be orphaned. Also, be sure that your deployment is `extension/v1beta1` api version. `kubectl` will always return `extension` api group even if your deployment is `apps/v1`. Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58131#issuecomment-356823588

Comment: Isn't this horrible though? I'm doing deployments with `skaffold` and it adds a label with its own version. So the moment I update `skaffold` itself - I can no longer deploy anything.

Answer (score 24):

This error is hard to read but it means that the labels specified in spec.template.metadata.labels of your Deployment definition do not match those of spec.selector.matchLabels within the same definition. Upload your YAML if you require further assistance. 
Best!

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to resolve this from what I can tell.  One way is to delete the deployment and re-apply the deployment with a key/value that works on your deployment:

```yaml
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app_name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app_name
        -- whatever else --
```

This obviously incurs downtime but should be permanent.  Your other option is to edit the deployment selector:

```sh
kubectl -n namespace edit deployment app-deployment
```

Then run your apply command again.  This may or may not be permanent as I don't know what changed the selector to begin with.

If your pod doesn't even exist yet to do modifications, this error might be legit.  You may have a pod with the same name in the same namespace.

Comment: Tried this today, and it worked, but I had to replace `app: app_name` with `name: app_name` in both places. I am a total newbie at this, so I offer this as a comment and not an authoritative correction.

Comment: indeed, your labels are self defined. makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Someone came to me with this issue and it turned out that they had typed "matadata" instead of "metadata" so as far as kubernetes was concerned the label wasn't defined, which lead to this error message.